# Formatting number in Eloquent query or Yarja Datatables

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-datatables

I am writing a searchable table which includes the area and population. Here is the basic query:

```
public function getCountryData()
  {
    $co = DB::table('countries')->leftJoin('country_detail','country_detail.country_id','=','countries.id')->addSelect(['countries.id','countries.name','country_detail.capital','country_detail.area','country_detail.iso3','country_detail.population','country_detail.currencyName','country_detail.phone','country_detail.continent'])->get();
    return Datatables::of($co)
    ->addColumn('action', function($co){
                            $btn = '<div style="float:right">
                            <a href="'. route('country.edit',$co->id) .'  " class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" title="edit" style="margin-right:.5em">'.getEditIcon().'</a><a href="'. route('country.show', $co->id) .'" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" title="images" style="margin-right:.5em">'.getBinoculars().'</a>';

                             return $btn;
                     }) ->rawColumns(['action'])
                 ->make(true);

  }
```

All this works fine in my view except that the population field, for example, returns something like 29121286 and of course I want to format it so it is 29,121,286.

Can this be done in the query or something in Datatables itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of formatting the number on client side using javascript, I suggest using php's `number_format` function to format your number.

```
return Datatables::editColumn('population', function($item) {
    return number_format($item->population);
});
```

For more help on formatting numbers, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: this is more convenient than frontend formatting

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Navok on Laracasts here is the answer.

Firstly you need a javascript function to convert the string to a number, properly formatted.

```
function formatNumber(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
}
```

I have added this in a file called misc.js (so I can have other things) which I call from the layouts.app so it is available system wide.

This can be found at https://blog.abelotech.com/posts/number-currency-formatting-javascript/.

Then within the datatables declaration on your page add

```
createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
        if (data.population !== undefined) {
            // 4 here is the cell number, it starts from 0 where this number should appear
            $(row).find('td:eq(4)').html(formatNumber(data.population)); 
        }
    },
```

I hope this is of value.